# how to log data in database at machine-generating speed

Tags: c++, database

I have a C++ application that generates a lot of data. I want to log these data into a database to be able to make fast select queries on it at a later time.
I tried using MYISAM storage engine in mysql but it tend to very slow insertion speed relative to the software-generating speed.

Any advice on a specific DBMS or anyway to do so?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice to just write to a file and then have another program parse and load that in a DB of your choice. The fastest DBs would be an in-memory DB like Redis, Tarantool or Memcached. Tune persistence settings to your requirements.